# How to call WCF service to WCF service in C#

Tags: c#, wcf

I am facing strange issue.

I have one WCF Library that is calling one external wcf service. and i am able to see the result as expected in test client.

But i have to host this WCF Library in IIS, for that i have to use one wcf service.
I refered Wcflibrary dll into the service, but getting the below error while creating object to external wcf service.

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.ServiceModel.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not find default endpoint element that
>   references contract 'SMSAgent.SMSGatewayPort' in the ServiceModel
>   client configuration section. This might be because no configuration
>   file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element
>   matching this contract could be found in the client element.

can any body please suggest.Is this scenario is having any issues?

Comment: The error is saying IIS cannot find an endpoint for this specific contract `SMSGatewayPort`. Double check your web.config file and make sure there's an endpoint defined for this service. Or are you creating the endpoints in the code?

Comment: If you are not creating the endpoint and binding to the external service programmatically upon calling it from your IIS hosted service (and external service client at the same time) you need to add the external.config enpoints and bindings into your.config just as you would do with any WCF client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no technical reason why you can't call a WCF service from another WCF service. You can chain as many service calls together as you like.

Let's call your calling service ServiceA and the external service ServiceB.

The error you are getting is saying that there is a problem with the client configuration in ServiceA. What this means is that the code telling WCF how to construct the client channel from ServiceA to ServiceB is missing or invalid.

Now, for each service you want to call, you need to define an [endpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731762(v=vs.110).aspx) inside the [client](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731704(v=vs.110).aspx) section in your `<system.serviceModel/>` configuration. Your endpoint definition must specify:

1. A name for the endpoint definition
2. The address of the service you are calling
3. Which transport binding the service is exposed over
4. The fully qualified name of the type containing the service definition

Optionally, you may need to include a [service identity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731721(v=vs.110).aspx) specification, depending on if the service you're calling requires authentication.

For example:

```
<client>
    <endpoint name="MyExternalEndpoint"
              address="http://externalservice.com"
              binding="wsHttpBinding" 
              contract="ExternalService.IServiceContract" >
      <identity>
        <dns value="externalservice.com" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
</client>
```

Comment: I am trying to consume a web service from another web service, while using mutual ssl for communication, somehow I'm having an issue with this when they are both hosted under the same IIS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44238239/wcf-client-inside-wcf-service-with-mutual-ssl?noredirect=1#comment75497248_44238239